# Unable to install and run iOS app on Simulator from command line - Simulator of iOS 6.1 Xcode 5 on mavericks

Tags: ios, command-line, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks, launch

I've tried various methods and scripts to launch my iOS compiled app via commandline but unable to do so, help will be appreciated.

I tried the following:

1. This command line:

   ```
   ./Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication App.app/App
   ```
2. [This](http://psellos.com/pub/ocamlxsim/runsim) shell script

Attempted on:

- Simulator app v7.0
- iOS 6.1
- Mac OSX Mavericks

No luck :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) (can be installed via Homebrew `brew install ios-sim`):

```
ios-sim launch <application path>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) just tested it and it works like a charm!

Comment: 1. To install your app
xcrun simctl install booted <app path>
2. To launch the app
xcrun simctl launch booted <app identifier>